# Is the cohomology of the dual operator of exterior differential operator isomorphic to homology?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

The dual operator of exterior derivative $d$ is given by $\delta = -*  d  *$, where $*$ is the Hodge operator. On the other hand, there is also a dual operator given by $\int _{\partial C} \omega = \int_C d\omega. $ These two operator $\delta, \partial$ make two homologies. Are these homogologies ismorphic?

Is there any reference or book explaining about this topic?

### Edit:

Using the Hodge operator as a chain map, we  get the following $$H^k_{DR}( \Omega^\bullet ,d) = H_k(\Omega^{n-\bullet}, \delta)  \cdots(1).$$

$$\begin{array}
A0
 & \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} 
& \mathbb{R} 
 & \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}
& \Omega^0
  & \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}
&\Omega^1
 & \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}
  &\Omega^2 
&\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}\\
\downarrow{*} & & \downarrow{*}&&\downarrow{*} && \downarrow{*}&&   \downarrow{*}&&\\
0
 & \stackrel{\delta}{\longrightarrow} 
& \mathbb{R} 
 & \stackrel{\delta}{\longrightarrow}
& \Omega^{n-0}
  & \stackrel{\delta}{\longrightarrow}
&\Omega^{n-1}
 & \stackrel{\delta}{\longrightarrow}
  &\Omega^{n-2} 
&\stackrel{\delta}{\longrightarrow}\\
\end{array}
$$

Furthermore, now $M$ is closed manifold,  so by the Poincare duality, it follows that $$H^k_{DR}( \Omega^\bullet ,d) = H_{n-k}(M, \mathbb{R}) \cdots(2)$$.

Combining (1) and (2),  the homology of the operator $\delta = -*d*$ is isomorphic to the singular homology; $ H_k(\Omega^{n-\bullet}, \delta) =  H_{n-k}(M, \mathbb{R}) $.

I am not sure about  the universal coefficients theorem ... I neet to learn about  the universal coefficients theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two (co)homologies are isomorphic, in the sense that the homology of the chain complexes gives you the same information (if we are talking about singular homology with real coefficients - integer coefficients capture more information). The reason for this is as follows: de Rham's theorem states that $H^k(M,\mathbb{R})\cong H^k_{dR}(M)$, where the former denotes singular cohomology with real coefficients, and the latter denotes de Rham cohomology. Now, the universal coefficients theorem implies that $H_k(M,\mathbb{R})\cong H^k(M,\mathbb{R})$. Furthermore, the $\delta$ operator is related to $d$ via the Hodge star operator, which is an isomorphism between the chain complex
$$0\to\Omega^n(M)\xrightarrow{\delta}\Omega^{n-1}(M)\xrightarrow{\delta}\dots$$
and the de Rham complex, and therefore there exists an isomorphism of homology groups $H_\bullet(\Omega^\bullet(M),\delta)\cong H_\bullet(C_\bullet(M,\mathbb{R}),\partial)$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $M$ is compact, oriented, and without boundary?